# How to get an unsaved print screen picture in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10

I need to recover a picture that I captured during an Interview process.
As I forgot to save the pic into an image file, I lost that screen capture.
I have copied some text later. Now my paste is printing some text only that is captured recently. Is there any other way to get the recent print screens that are unsaved. Can we find any default locations where these print screen entries are saved ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reckon Windows 10 allows you to see your Clipboard's recent history by clicking Windows + V keys. If so, as screenshots are copied to your clipboard, there might be some possibilities to find it.

Apart from that, I would say you can also sync the screen prints to One Drive so they get automatically saved, but you should have enabled it before.